# Применение фильтров к фону в html

Tags: html, css, изображения, фильтры

У меня есть 3 блока.
Первый - фоновая картинка, подключенная через `CSS`. Два остальных вложены в первый блок и представляют собой одну картинку, подключенную уже в `html` и немного текста.
Я хочу применить фильтр только к фоновому изображению, чтобы этот фильтр не задел два блока  вложенных в него.
Использовать отступы не хотелось бы.

```css
.layer
{
 height: 530px;
 background-image: url(../img/imgbox.png);
        filter: brightness(55%);
}
```

```html
<div class="layer">
 <div class="tabble"><img src="img/bxccl.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Дополните вопрос своим кодом

Comment: это не возможно ... так как они унаследуют правила от своего родителя ...это как ДНК ...можно избежать наследия только если родитель другой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно фоновую картинку вынести в псевдоэлемент и применить фильтр к нему.

```css
.layer {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
}

.layer::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/any);
  filter: brightness(55%);
}

.tabble {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="layer">
  <div class="tabble">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any">
  </div>
</div>
```