# Размытый фон для изображения

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть `div` с размытым фоновым изображением, если сверху вставить текст, то он тоже размывается, нужно чтобы текст не размывался. С `z-index` играл, не получилось.

```css
div {
  height: calc(100vh - 0.97rem);
  background: silver url('http://blog.routeperfect.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/shutterstock_172557722.jpg');
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Применение фильтров к фону в html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837233/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b2-html)

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.items {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
  filter: blur(2px);
}
  p{ 
   font-weight: bold;
   text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white; }
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://st.gde-fon.com/wallpapers_original/wallpapers/446464_(www.Gde-Fon.com).jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae incidunt fugiat suscipit tenetur vel reprehenderit sapiente praesentium, labore ullam consequuntur.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: рекомендую вставить еще что-то вроде этого, а то трудно читать текст: `p { font-weight: bold; text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white; }`

Comment: @SamYonnou добавил